# Dealing with hotlinking and old references after rebuild in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I just launched a completely rebuilt in rails website and am using New Relic for error monitoring. I've been getting a lot of errors and alerts for what I'm guessing is people using bookmarks for pages/paths that no longer exist and possibly some hot linking.

What is the best way to resolve this situation so that I stop getting the alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ignoring those errors?

> ignore_errors - A comma separated list of Exception classes which will
>   be ignored
>
> In addition, the error collector can be customized programmatically
>   for more control over filtering. In your application initialization,
>   you can register a block with the Agent to be called when an error is
>   detected. The block should return the error to record, or nil if the
>   error is to be ignored. For example:
>
> ```
>   config.after_initialize do
>     ::NewRelic::Agent.ignore_error_filter do |error|
>       if error.message =~ /gateway down/
>         nil
>       elsif
>         error.class.name == "InvalidLicenseException"
>         StandardError.new "We should never see this..."
>       else
>         error
>       end
>     end
>   end
> ```

([source](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration))

Comment: What kind of errors do you get precisely? I guess you can render a nice 404 page for those missing pages?

Comment: I was thinking that I could reroute some of the more common 404's that people are getting. Is that advisable?

Comment: Why not? Whatever you feel like.